# mcrypt_create_iv Fatal error:Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04

hello stackoverflow guys:

1.What I am trying to do is to bulid a opensource web(leaninglock) on the server( success done on my local win7 ).

Picture1 shows the error I met [picture1](http://d.pcs.baidu.com/thumbnail/affadd9b1ba9a27c0579306d1fa87542?fid=1259200580-250528-43795242587230&time=1441854000&rt=pr&sign=FDTAER-DCb740ccc5511e5e8fedcff06b081203-NQOMRP18B3caXrJffmwn1gSo0z8%3D&expires=8h&prisign=unknow&chkbd=0&chkv=0&size=c1920_u1080&quality=90) -----Sorry no reputation to post img and links.

My Server environment: Ubuntu 12.04, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5.28, and I am totally new to Linux and php and stackoverflow.

2.I tested with simple code:

```
<?php
echo "hello-----<br>";
$r = MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM;//MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM;
echo $r;
mcrypt_create_iv(1,$r);
echo "---------end";
?>
```

and get:

```
hello-----
0
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/test.php on line 5
```

I also have tried to set max_execution_time = 0, it takes about 1min and show the same error(30 -> 0).

Waiting help V_V...

Comment: maybe follow the sample in http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php.  this is just getting an IV of length 1?

Comment: @ClaytonWilkinson  I set $size = 1 to make the code simple.I tried the sample in php.net($size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB)) , it still not wok.%>_<%

Comment: from the manual: Note that MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM may block until more entropy is available.  So mcrypt_create_iv *can* be a blocking call.